# How to add image preview for Flutter web app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, url, flutter-web

I created a web app using flutter and hosted that using firebase. With firebase I got a hosting url as **app-name.web.app**

> **SO is there a way to add an image preview whenever I share that url on social media?**

In the image below, 1st url doesn't have any preview image, and in the second url we can see the image preview.

[image: EG: Here there is no preview for url1 but there is for url2]

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean the `<meta property="og:image" content="<URL to your image>">` tag

This tags are used for social media sharing. There are several more.

- og:title – Title of the page
- og:image – URL to your image --> this is what you want to use
- og:type – Type (eg. article)
- og:url - URL to this specific page

Have a look at [Open Graph protocol](https://ogp.me/)

Add the tags you need to your *web/index.html*.